# PDO, was the query done correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

Could this method be used to check if the insert (or other types of queries) was done successfully?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable (info, address, phone) VALUES (?,?,?)';
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);

if ($sth->execute(array($info, $address, $phone))) {
   // success!, now do something
}
```

Or will it return true even if nothing was inserted, but the prepare/query itself was ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is true if no error/warning is raised internally. It has nothing to do with the actual result of the query, it just means that your query is syntaxically correct and didn't break any database constraint.

Said differently: if you run your query successfully in the database using your sql editor, but 0 rows are affected, it would still return true in php.

Comment: Ok, so instead I should use: `if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) { // do something }` ?

Comment: Ok. I just check if lastinsertid is not null? Or is_numeric + !empty?

Comment: they also suggest another method `OUTPUT INSERTED...` in the comments, interesting

Comment: Yes if the statement ("where something = something") does not match, I guess

Comment: But an insert doesnt have such requirements. It should insert the data as expected. Please check you have autocommit = ON

Comment: hm somehow $sth->lastInsertId() outputs no number

Comment: The php doc on lastinsertid has no examples :/

Comment: Then nothing got inserted. That's curious... Did you disable errors? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: [PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Errors and warnings + notice is enabled. It did get inserted. I see now that I have to use the DATABASE and not the query, like so: $conn->lastInsertId() and not $sth->lastInsertId()

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't had an error raised for that

Comment: Hehe ok it's because this is for a javascript thing, so not so easy.. I had to make a test page. Anyway, thanks. But I think I'll stick to rowCount() for now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have done it the right way, you can make it more verbose like this:

```
if ($sth->execute((array($info, $address, $phone))) {
   // success!, now do something
   echo 'lastInsertId = '.$conn->lastInsertId(); 

} else {
   // Query failed.
   echo 'errorcode = '.$sth->errorCode();
}
```